# Selectable Recipient with Pipes Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress

I have integrating contact form 7 plugin for mail functionality. On different services, mail should be delivered to different emailIDs. For that i have used dropdown with selectable pipe. I want to call this Select Recipient in "To field" in mail section from backend so that mail functionality work differently for each service.

Answer (score 1):

First fill out the shortcode in the "Form" Tab of the Contact Form 7 Dashboard, such as `[select* email-recipient “Sales|sales@yourdomain.com” “Tech Support|support@yourdomain.com” “Inquiry|info@yourdomain.com”]`, which it sounds like you have already done.

Then navigate to the "mail" tab and enter the corresponding tag for your select fields. In the example above, I would use `[email-recipient]` in order to dynamically select the appropriate email address.